# Где и как хранить изображения?

Tags: laravel, изображения

Сделал небольшой проект на Laravel, где пользователи имеют возможность загружать изображения. По мере роста кол-ва пользователей, папочка с картинками разрастается до неприличного и размер моего хостинга уже начинает давить. Хотел бы поинтересоваться, как с изображениями работать? а то подобного опыта еще не было у меня. Мб как то сжать можно без потери качества или облака какие нибудь?

Comment: Либо сжимать (но со временем место всё равно закончится), либо увеличивать место на хостинге. Зачем вообще давать юзерам возможность неограниченной загрузки изображений?

Answer (score 0):

В laravel можно настроить работу с облачными файловыми системами, например, из коробки идёт возможность работать с S3: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem .